# bash: How to replace all variable names with their values after `cat` a file?

Tags: linux, bash, replace, echo, cat

`A.txt` contains the following: `$x + $y = $z`

I want to `cat A.txt` which will echo `$x + $y = $z`, but I want the variables to be replaced with their values, Any way?

Let's look at another simple test:
 `B.txt` contains `$x` , we can use `` echo `echo \$x` `` but neither `echo $(echo \$x)` nor `` echo `cat B.txt` ``

Why `cat` dosn't work? and how to do it?

Comment: If you have access to `envsubst` (from gettext-base package) and your variables are already exported: `envsubst < A.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I could think of is

```
x=2
y=1
z=3
cat A.txt | sed -e "s/\$x/$x/" -e "s/\$y/$y/" -e"s/\$z/$z/"
```

This is not very dynamic though.

Comment: Actually I have 120 variable (24 hours * 5 columns) and I WILL NOT USE `sed` for that, I am searching for an alternative, automatic replacement.

Answer (score -1):

use eval:

```
$ x=1
$ y=2
$ z=3    
$ eval echo $(<A.txt)
1 + 2 = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, but why `eval cat A.txt` dosn't work like this ?

Comment: `eval echo $(cat A.txt)` eval replace all the variables to their value. `eval cat A.txt` doesn't contain any variable, so it runs `cat A.txt`.

Comment: @Ipo This does not work if A.txt contains redirections. In such a case you should run something like `while read line; do eval echo '"'$line'"'; done < A.txt`

Comment: @davidedb Integers contain redirections in very rare  cases.